# React: Understanding passing functions

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing the React Tutorial (https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) and there is one thing I don't understand: Near the end (here's the code: https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/EmmOqJ?editors=0010), when the handleClick function is lifted up to the highest level (Game) and then passed over to the Board and then the Square level, for the first time the notation at the Game level "changes" to `(i)` instead of just `()`. So, the code is now `onClick={(i) => this.handleClick(i)}` (line 86) while at the Board level it's `onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}` (line 14). What determines whether I have to pass arguments or not?

Comment: You have to pass an argument if you're going to use that argument. If you (nor any function you eventually call) don't use the argument, you can omit it.

Comment: At the renderSquare inside the Board component the i variable is already defined, so it simply passes down to the Square component a function without parameters. If you take a closer look you will notice that the Square component does not have an index, so it could not invoke the onClick function passing the index parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear things, I'll explain the implications behind what's happening.

This is an ES6 function:

```
() => {}
```

In ES5 the equivalent would be:

```
function(){}
```

In `renderSquare`, a Square Component is returned like this:

```
<Square
  value={this.props.squares[i]}
  onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}
/>
```

This means we execute a function, which calls `this.props.onClick(i)`, when the Square is clicked. As you see, the parameter `i` of `renderSquare` is passed to `this.props.onClick`.

In the Game Component we render a different the Board component.

```
<Board
  squares={current.squares}
  onClick={(i) => this.handleClick(i)}
/>
```

The function passed to `onClick` differs.
We pass this function to onClick (in ES6):

```
(i) => this.handleClick(i)
```

In ES5 that would look like:

```
function(i){
  this.handleClick(i)
}.bind(this)
```

(the bind method is related to function scoping, you don't need to care about that now, the function is the important part)

Back to Game Components `render` method:

```
<Board
  squares={current.squares}
  onClick={(i) => this.handleClick(i)}
/>
```

As you see the function has a parameter `i`. It gets assigned in the Game component to the prop `onClick`. This `onClick` prop is now available on the Board Component. In `renderSquare` we are just calling the same function. The function we just passed to the `onClick` prop. The function is now just called over the prop of the Board component, like that:

```
this.props.onClick(i)
```

So we are passing the `i` up as the Square is clicked.
The order is as follows:

- Square gets clicked
- assigned onClick EventHandler in Board component is called
  -> calls this.props.onClick(i), meaning the onClick EventHandler on the Game Component is called with the argument `i`

That's why the function requires an `i` in it's definition like this:

```
(i) => this.handleClick(i)
```

The i is passed up from the Board component to the Game component and will be used by the handleClick function.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. And also thanks to the other commenters above. So, in a way, one could say that passing goes both ways, right? It creates a "binding" of variables between the different component levels, in this case between the "i" of the handleClick method and the one of the renderSquare methods. Well, this whole system of passing things around still seems overly complicated to me for now, will hopefully get used to it. ;-)

Comment: @Adrian Yes kind of. In the Game component, your could call this a callback function
onClick={(i) => this.handleClick(i)}
It reacts to the onClick from the Square Component and gives you the variable 'i'.
I think callbacks are the only way to pass data from a child component up to the parent component (besides Context and State Management libs like Redux/MobX)
This article might also help you https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/callback-functions-in-react-e822ebede766
The infographic is very informative.